# Access template reference variables from component class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

```
<div>
   <input #ipt type="text"/>
</div>
```

Is it possible to access the template access variable from the component class?

i.e., can I access it here,

```
class XComponent{
   somefunction(){
       //Can I access #ipt here?
   }
}
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

That is a use-case for `@ViewChild`:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html

```
class XComponent {
   @ViewChild('ipt', { static: true }) input: ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      // this.input is NOW valid !!
   }

   somefunction() {
       this.input.nativeElement......
   }
}
```

Here's a working demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchilddemo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: But on debugging I am getting this.input itself as undefined.

Comment: As i mentioned, its only available AFTER the event `ngAfterViewInit()` was fired. You have to import `ViewChild` from '@angular/core` ..

Comment: But how can we set a value?
I've tried `this.ipt.nativeElement.setAttribute('value', 'xxx');` but nothing happens. And there are no methods like `value()` or `setValue()`, even if I declare it of type HTMLInputElement (I'm basing this on IDE's code hinting/autocomplete).

In my case, I don't care about reading the value. I just need to set different values.

Comment: Currently in Holiday.. did you tried `setProperty` also?

Comment: doesn't seem to exist. Throws an error in the console `.setProperty is not a function` on `this.ipt.nativeElement.setProperty('value', 'xxx');`

Anyway, the more I think of it, I shouldn't touch the dom. I just don't want to make the input part of any formGroup because it doesn't contain any relevant data for sending to the server and wanted to find another way rather than having to filter it out before sending the data.

Comment: shouldnt `this.input.nativeElement.value = 'test'` work?! maybe there are special behaviors with forms and their bindings.

Comment: @mxii 
I forked your plunker and access the ref-var using queries in the decorator instead. It seems to work
https://plnkr.co/edit/RBLIYdrVfv6toCnie9es?p=info

But on my own code, without declaring input variable within the App class, IDE WebStorm complains that input variable doesn't exist on type App. Have you had such experience?

Comment: Yes, I tried in the plunker and worked:
    `this.input.nativeElement.value = 'test'`

Comment: Me I used @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: NgModel; in order to be able to access the validation features of the angular form object - like this.myInput.invalid.

Answer (score 5):

```
@ViewChild('modal reference variable', { static: true }) name: ElementRef;
```

sometimes it doesn't work on modal. so when I used modal in angular it gives an error so I use this.

```
@ViewChild('modal reference variable', { static: true }) name!: ElementRef;
```

it will definitely work if you want the modal to be executed without clicking the button.

Comment: or `@ViewChild('modal reference variable', { static: true }) name: ElementRef | undefined;` so you dont forget it really is `undefined` before `ngAfterViewInit()`