# document.getElementById replacement in angular4 / typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with angular4 in my practice work, and this is new for me.

In order to get HTML elements and their values, I used `<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById` or `<HTMLSelectElement> document.getElementById`.

I'm wondering if there is any replacement for this in angular.

Comment: Why not use getElementById?

Comment: Just wondering it there is an angular way to get elements.

Comment: Because we don't want to use `document`. There are many advanced reasons to want to do this.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You can tag your DOM element using `#someTag`, then get it with `@ViewChild('someTag')`.

See complete example:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <div #myDiv>Some text</div>
    `,
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

`console.log` will print *Some text*.

Comment: Error shows up

Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/metadata/di'
Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/linker/element_ref'

Comment: nvm, solved by importing like this.
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

Comment: it won't work if you have conditional dom element like *ngFor, *ngIf etc

Comment: Angular 8+ requires *two* arguments to the ViewChild decorator.

Comment: @RavindraThorat In Angular 8+, you can supply `{static: false}` as the second argument to the ViewChild decorator and whenever the item gets visible, your reference will point to it.

Comment: How to do that with Reactive forms/Dynamic form controls without template ref?

Comment: With newer TS Version you need to either disable strict mode or set `myDiv` as potentially `undefined`:

`@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef | undefined`;

Answer (score 123):

You can just inject the [**DOCUMENT**](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) token into the constructor and use the same functions on it

```
import { Inject }  from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 

@Component({...})
export class AppCmp {
   constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document) {
      document.getElementById('el');
   }
}
```

Or if the element you want to get is in that component, you can use [**template references**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631594/angular-2-is-it-possible-to-access-template-reference-variables-from-the-compo).

Comment: Why should I inject the document object and not use directly that provided by javascript?

Comment: @Davide we rely on the system of Angular. Later they can implement very good things and do some checking in their implementation. So we just rely on the abstraction here

Answer (score 39):

**For Angular 8 or posterior @ViewChild have an additional parameter** called opts, which have two properties: read and static, read is optional. You can use it like so:

```js
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
// ...
@ViewChild('mydiv', { static: false }) public mydiv: ElementRef;

constructor() {
// ...
```

```html
<div #mydiv></div>
```

NOTE: Static: false is not required anymore in Angular 9. (just `{ static: true }` when you are going to use that variable inside ngOnInit)

Comment: It works when you dynamically hide or show elements using `*ngIf`. How are you creating the element?

Comment: Thank you for supplying updated syntax.  

It's worth noting that you still can't just grab any HTML element by tag name with `@ViewChild('myDiv'...` in Angular 8.  You can only grab an element in the component's markup tagged with a template variable, e. g. `#mydiv`.  I almost missed that your answer contained the variable tag on the element.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

TypeScript file code:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("name")).value
```

HTML code:

```
 <input id="name" type="text" #name />
```

Comment: Please describe what 'name' attribute or value you are referring to with getElementById("name") because it could be either the id or the #name

Answer (score 10):

```
  element: HTMLElement;

  constructor() {}

  fakeClick(){
    this.element = document.getElementById('ButtonX') as HTMLElement;
    this.element.click();
  }
```

Comment: This is very unsafe (running this command in Angular Universal causes a crash) and should only be used if no other option is possible (also consider that the element may not be present)

Comment: M@Joniras why is it very unsafe?

Comment: Because you are manipulating/accessing directly the native DOM. It is recommended that you access HTML elements using Angular's DOM API (for example ViewChild, Renderer2 or ElementRef), as they are designed to ensure consistency, security, and maintainability. Touching directly the native DOM with document.getElementById bypasses this security and can lead to several issues. Check: https://dev.to/imsabodetocode/dom-manipulations-in-angular-1dh1