# Angular : Fetch value of textbox onclick of button

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to print the value of textbox when i click of button. But it throws nullpointerexception. I also need to keep some value in the textbox i dont understand why?. Whatever i type in textbox and when i click on buttom i need to print the value of textbox What is the issue?

Below is my code:

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mypage',
  templateUrl: './mypage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mypage.component.scss']
})
export class mypageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



  myFunc() {

      var num1 = ((document.getElementById("exchageRateDate") as HTMLInputElement).value);
      console.log(num1);
  }

}
```

**HTML File**

```
<br>Welcome.<br>
Place - <input type="text" value="Sydney" ng-model="placeId" />
<button (click)="myFunc(placeId)" formtarget="_blank">Test</button>
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Comment: Usually manipulating the dom directly in Angular application is discouraged. I would use a template variable to reference the input and pass the value directly to myFunc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to add `id` in input field

```
<input id="exchageRateDate" type="text" value="Sydney" ng-model="placeId" />
```

**Edit**: Angular way to do it

As you are using Angular so I will suggest you a better way to do this using [**NgModel**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

Try this

```
<br>Welcome.<br>
Place - <input type="text" value="Sydney" [(ngModel)]="placeId" />
<button (click)="myFunc(placeId)" formtarget="_blank">Test</button>
```

In component:

```
myFunc(num1) {
  console.log(num1);//here you will get input value through ng-model
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set id of input tag remove ng-model because it's a **angularjs(1.x.x)** not **angular(2/4/5/6/7/8)**

In html

```
<br>Welcome.<br>
 Place - <input id="exchageRateDate" type="text" value="Sydney"  />
 <button (click)="myFunc()" formtarget="_blank">Test</button>
```

In typescript:

```
myFunc() {
    var num1 = ((document.getElementById("exchageRateDate") as HTMLInputElement).value);
    console.log(num1);
}
```

Here is working example: [Get value of input tag using HTMLInputElement](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbp2wg)

Comment: Why do you want to use "document.getElementById()" here when we can use a binding that would keep things sane.

Comment: It would be better to use a "ViewChild" instead. It's much more closed to "Angular" approach. Check the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226955/2408212).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" id="Summary" name="Summary"placeholder="Summary" value="{{Item.summary}}">
(document.getElementById("Summary") as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written