# Is it possible to covert an entire application developed using php,javascript,html to angular 7?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular

I have developed an application using javascript,php,html with a lot of ajax calls . I was planning to convert this entire application to angular 7. Is it possible to do this without re-doing the entire application from scratch in angular ?
If this is possible,could you please tell me how to get started with this?
Thank you

Comment: Not possible. Angular is a javascript framework which handles ajax calls in different way when compare to javascript.

Comment: You cannot directly convert that into angular. You have to rewrite the application using angular

Comment: Short answer, NO, is not possible, you'll need to do a lot of things.

Comment: Of course it's possible. By re-writing the entire application. By hand, because there is no automated way to convert the code.

Comment: Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's always better to rewrite the entire application. But the effort you put to that will be worth it. You can start by creating a new angular application and adding your code module by module

Answer (score 0):

It is a manual process and you would have to re-do it from scratch.

There are many examples online: **[Here is one](https://www.djamware.com/post/5bca67d780aca7466989441f/angular-7-tutorial-building-crud-web-application)**

Answer (score 0):

As Angular is a complete framework and not just a library, it has it's very own concepts. So even if you might be able to "squeeze" some of your javascript code into the angular application, it wouldn't be a clean solution.

One example would be how you access DOM elements in javascript and angular: the javascript approach with `getElementById()` etc. works, but it's not the way recommended by angular. (Example: [document.getElementById replacement in angular4 / typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226868/document-getelementbyid-replacement-in-angular4-typescript/48226924))

So like other answers already suggest, a mostly automatic conversion is not possible. But you can still transform your existing concept and ideas of you current app to a new angular app.