# ngAfterViewInit is not working or am I doing something wrong

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My ngAfterViewInit function is not working as expected. I have feeling that I am missing something here.

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {this.users = users) ;  
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (document.getElementById('target')) {
        document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'auto',
          block: 'center',
          inline: 'center',
       });
   }
```

So basically, I'm using `ngAfterViewInint()` function to scroll to the current item, after the view complete loaded. Inside `ngOnInit()`, if I am not calling `subscribe()` and just put a variable there. It works just fine. But its not the case that what i am asking.

I have a work around by using `setTimeOut()` inside `ngAfterViewInit()`. But I don't like it. I dont like the fact that its relies on timeout. And I think there would be a better solution for it. 
Any ideal ? Thanks all.

Comment: Does your `target` element depend on data returning from your request?

Comment: You cannot refer to elements like this in angular 2+ Refer to this on calling child native elements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226868/document-getelementbyid-replacement-in-angular4-typescript

Comment: @Pyth yes. it is.

Comment: @Rager Thanks. let me try.

Comment:  I think `@ViewChildren` is the perfect way her , I have include my answer hope its helpful 

Answer (score 6):

a better solution is to use `ViewChildren` decorator because you can subscribe to changes of the view this mean you don't need to use `setTimeOut`

```js
  @ViewChildren("target") target: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {this.users = users) ;  
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.target.changes.subscribe(({ first: elm }) => {

      elm.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "auto",
        block: "center",
        inline: "center"
      });

    });
  }
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-view-changes)

Comment: @all readers don't forget in this case target is not a HTML ID like in OPs question but an Angular template variable <div #target></div>

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your code depends on your `dataService.getUsers()` call returning before `ngAfterViewInit()` gets invoked?

If so, that's not going to work, because there's no guarantee about the timing.
Instead, do this:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
      this.users = users;
      this.scrollTargetIntoView();
   )};
 }

  scrollTargetIntoView() {
    if (document.getElementById('target')) {
        document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'auto',
          block: 'center',
          inline: 'center',
       });
   }
```

Even this may be a bit too early - you may want to add a setTimeout() to this to give the DOM a chance to be rendered, e.g.:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
      this.users = users;
      setTimeout(() => this.scrollTargetIntoView());
   )};
 }

  scrollTargetIntoView() {
    if (document.getElementById('target')) {
        document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'auto',
          block: 'center',
          inline: 'center',
       });
   }
```

Comment: I had to use this technique once.
I needed to wait for DOM loaded to pass ID of "select" tag element inside Angular template to external JS-file to style it.

Answer (score 2):

If your Angular app has routing, then another option you can look into is [Route Resolvers](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/), which can pre-fetch data for a component before navigating to a certain route. This way, your UI will have all the necessary data it needs to render in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook.

You can create a resolver service using the following code:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<User[]>> {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  resolve() {
    return this.dataService.getUsers()
  }
}
```

And then in your route definitions, you can activate the resolver using:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my_path',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
      users: UserResolverService
    }
  }
];
```

And then finally, in your components `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook, you can consume the data using the following code:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.users = this.route.snapshot.data.users;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (document.getElementById('target')) {
    document.getElementById('target').scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'auto',
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'center',
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case interface implementation was missing (**implements AfterViewInit**):

```
export class BlaBlaClass extends BaseBlaBla implements AfterViewInit
```

Also the import section lookslike:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'
```