# javascript's getElementsByClassName length not working in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

A simple javascript file is running absolute fine, But when I try to insert those code in angular (from assets OR inserting code in index.html file) giving unexpected value.

```
HTML code
<p class='collect'> this is text </p>
<p class='collect'> this is text </p>
<p class='collect'> this is text </p>
```

```
//js in separate file

var all = document.getElementsByClassName('collect');
console.log(all.length);

//returns 3
```

```
//js code in angular

var all = document.getElementsByClassName('collect');
console.log(all);

// returns 
HTMLCollection []
length: 3
0: p.collect
1: p.collect
2: p.collect 

// but in
console.log(all.length);
// returns 0
```

Comment: How do they look in the DOM?

Comment: You're probably running the code in Angular too soon in the page lifecycle. Can you post the context of where it's called.

Comment: Try document.querySelector('.classname')

Answer (score 1):

You should try `document.querySelector('.collect')`.

Comment: using the ClassName selector is necessary , I need elements in the array

Comment: @AmitKumawat, Is this is what you want? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtumlo

Comment: thanks @ManirajMurugan, but you did it from ts file, can you do it from js file ? like adding js file in assets, or inside a script tag in index.html.

Comment: @AmitKumawat, You mean like this?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtumlo?file=index.html

Comment: thanks @ManirajMurugan, actually DOM is loaded before the execution of code, I found some more ways to avoid this situation including yours.

Comment: @AmitKumawat, You can try the methods inside ```ngAfterviewInit()``` lifecycle hook if dom is loaded initially..Anyhow happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226868/document-getelementbyid-replacement-in-angular4-typescript) and I think you need to inject DOCUMENT in orden to work:

(I'm assuming you are using Angular and not AngularJS

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 

@Component({...})
export class AppCmp {
   constructor(private document: DOCUMENT) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('collect');
      console.log(all.length);
   }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I dont think injecting document is required.. OP can access the element using ElementRef , ViewChild or simply using queryselector

Comment: yes, of course, but this answer is if you need/want to use `document`. There are alternatives too as you said, @ViewChild being one.

Comment: For using document, injection is not required. And you answer says I think you need to inject Document.. this might create confusion

Answer (score 0):

length is coming zero because till the time Angular component which having these p tags, has not loaded in dom.
So put this code inside lifecycle hook ngAfterViewChecked.

Comment: I think they are loaded because on console.log(all);

// returns 
HTMLCollection []
length: 3
0: p.collect
1: p.collect
2: p.collect 

// but in
console.log(all.length);
// returns 0