# How to add smoothie chart in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, smoothie.js

I am very beginner in Angular 8, I am adding smoothie chart in my Angular 8, there no tutorial in google smoothie chart added to angular 8 help me to solve this or give me examples

1. npm install smoothie added my angular 8 project
2. import {SmoothieChart} from "smoothie"; added to app.component.ts

Code:

```
import {SmoothieChart} from "smoothie";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'dashboard';
  constructor(){}
    ngOnInit()
    {

      var smoothie = new SmoothieChart();

    }
}
```

App.component.html

```
<div>
  <canvas id="mycanvas" width="800" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

In Javascript smoothie .streamTo(document.getElementById("chart"), 500);
In angular 8 how to add above code

Comment: Refer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226868/document-getelementbyid-replacement-in-angular4-typescript

For Life-cycle refer this.  https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to let Angular initialize the DOM, so you can't do it in the `ngOnInit` (because the element is not yet inserted in the DOM), you need to implement [for example `AfterViewInit` and the related method `ngAfterViewInit`.](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Then, you could use `document.getElementById` but it's not the best way to achieve it in Angular, you should [use `@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to retrieve the related element.